# "Threshold value" -- first to be accepted or last to be rejected?

Tags: meaning

Let's say I'm talking about an integer value `x`, which divides all integers into accepted or rejected.

If I'm calling this *the threshold value*, then which interpretation feels more natural?

- values need to be *at least* `x` to be accepted
- values need to be *over* `x` to be accepted

(If I'm not mistaken, then *threshold value* can be also used when smaller values are preferred. Let's assume here that it is clear from the context, that larger values have better chance to be accepted.)

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer *any value* ***under*** *x will be rejected.* It clearly indicates that *x* is the number you want to aim for. (And I find the phrasing a bit more natural.)

Comment: They (*over* vs *at least*) mean different things, depending on whether *x* itself is accepted. Pick whichever wording matches your intent.

Comment: @Lawrence, my question is not about the meaning or wording of these two phrases but about the expression "threshold value" itself. I'd like to know which of the two phrases people usually mean when they say "threshold value".

Comment: Both will work. They do not mean the same. Look up the words in a dictionary for the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *threshold* discriminates between values above and below it.

If a value lies *at* the threshold, it doesn't default to either. It might even be considered a special value that belongs to neither.

For example, 0 is a threshold value discriminating between positive and negative numbers while not being either positive *or* negative.

The expressions "the threshold *above* which something happens" and "the threshold *at* which something happens" are [both idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=threshold%20at%20which%2Cthreshold%20above%20which&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthreshold%20at%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthreshold%20above%20which%3B%2Cc0). The former excludes the threshold value while the latter includes it.

Dictionary definitions (even from the same dictionary) bear this out. Consider these definitions from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/threshold):

> 2 The magnitude or intensity that must be exceeded for a certain reaction, phenomenon, result, or condition to occur or be manifested.
> ‘nothing happens until the signal passes the threshold’
>
> 2.1 The maximum level of radiation or a concentration of a substance considered to be acceptable or safe.
> ‘their water would meet the safety threshold of 50 milligrams of nitrates per litre’
>
> 2.2 The level at which one starts to feel or react to something.
> ‘he has a low boredom threshold’
>
> 2.3 A level, rate, or amount at which something comes into effect.
> ‘the inheritance tax threshold’

The wording of definition 2 excludes the threshold from the "accepted values", whereas that of definitions 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 include it.

You asked:

> “Threshold value” — first to be accepted or last to be rejected?

Without further context, it is ambiguous. There are grounds to consider it to be either or even neither.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to go is to write "minimum" or "maximum" before "threshold."

So if you write "minimum threshold value x," you mean "at least x." And if you write "maximum threshold value x," you mean "not more than x."